# How to select element with many tags using Javascript querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, selectors-api

I'm trying to select the element below using Javascript querySelectorAll():

```
<button aria-label="Show more replies" data-open-web-class="conversation-message-show-replies" type="button" class="Button__button--11-3-6 Button__action--11-3-6 Button__isEllipsis--11-3-6 spcv_showMoreRepliesText">1 reply</button>
```

I'm new to Javascript, but searching around, I figured solution should be:

```
document.querySelectorAll('button.Show more replies.conversation-message-show-replies.Button__button--11-3-6.Button__action--11-3-6 Button__isEllipsis--11-3-6.spcv_showMoreRepliesText');
```

Unfortunately, I'm not getting a result set. So either my syntax is wrong, or there's something I'm not understanding.

Can someone show me how to select the above element, so I can compare against my answer and learn my mistake? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`querySelector()` -- Selects 1 element [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
`querySelectorAll()` -- Selects a NodeList of elements [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

If you are just selecting one instance of this button use `querySelector`
It accepts a valid CSS selector, so to select this button with its class, use the `.` plus its class :

```
querySelector(".Button__button--11-3-6.Button__action--11-3-6.Button__isEllipsis--11-3-6.spcv_showMoreRepliesText")
```

Or you can select with attributes such as:

```
querySelector("button[data-open-web-class=conversation-message-show-replies]")
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to select every aspect of this button. I think just the class(es) would be enough. Also, since you're selecting just one element, I think `document.querySelector` is more suitable.

```js
document.querySelector('button.Button__button--11-3-6.Button__action--11-3-6.Button__isEllipsis--11-3-6.spcv_showMoreRepliesText').style.color='red';
```

```html
<button aria-label="Show more replies" data-open-web-class="conversation-message-show-replies" type="button" class="Button__button--11-3-6 Button__action--11-3-6 Button__isEllipsis--11-3-6 spcv_showMoreRepliesText">1 reply</button>
```